# Unit test by mocking external DLL using Moq in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to write a unit test for one of my functions which has dependency on a external DLL. I decided to use Moq (Mocking to external dependency) to test my function.

MyClass has one function and an external dependency.

```
namespace MyService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MyClass
    /// </summary>
    public class MyClass : IMyClass
    {
        private ExternalClass ex;
        public MyClass() {
            ex = new ExternalClass();
        }
        public bool publish(string param) {
           if(... param is not valid)
              throw error;
           return ex.externalPublish(param);
        }
    }
}
```

External class publish function calls some runtime dependency so that function can not be expected to run during unit tests

```
namespace ExternalService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ExternalClass
    /// </summary>
    public class ExternalClass : IExternalClass, OtherExternalClass // OtherExternalClass is a concrete one, not an interface
    {
        public ExternalClass(){}

        public bool publish(string param) {
           // some implementation which contacts database, other running services etc.
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace MyServiceTests
{
    using Moq;
     /// <summary>
    /// MyClass test
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class MyClassTest
    {
      
        /// <summary>
        /// Publish
        /// </summary>
        [TestMethod]
        public void PublishTestSucceed()
        {
            var moq = new Mock<ExternalClass>(); // I tried IExternalClass but it is not the only inheritence that ExternalClass has.
            moq.CallBase = true;
            moq.Setup(tsmv2 => tsmv2.publish(
                It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns(true);


            MyClass myC = new MyClass();
            PrivateObject obj = new PrivateObject(myC);

            obj.SetField("ex", moq.Object); // If I use IExternalClass to create moq, I am not able to convert IExternalClass to ExternalClass here.

            bool result = myC.publish("asdf");
            Assert.IsTrue(result);
        }
```

So two problems:

1. The external class is not entirely dependent on just one Interface. Can I still use Moq library here?
2. Even if I use the interface I am not able to convert the `moq.Object` to IExternalClass object even with explicit casting.

Comment: **Problem:** _you need to test your software_.  You decide to using _mocking_.  Now you have _two problems_.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/362622/1996

Comment: Extract the dependency `MyClass` has into its own interface that you do control and can mock, and inject that as a dependency on construction. In other words, build a bridge. Note that if this reduces `MyClass` to something trivial, that would mean `MyClass` is itself already bridging/adapting and testing it is not useful (instead the classes that use *it* should be tested).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subject under test is tightly coupled to concrete external implementation details and should be dependent on an abstraction using explicit dependency principle via constructor injection.

Refactored subject class:

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass {
    private IExternalClass ex;

    public MyClass(IExternalClass ex) {
        this.ex = ex;
    }

    public bool publish(string param) {
       if(... param is not valid)
          throw error;
       return ex.publish(param); //... external call
    }
}
```

It really should not matter to the subject class that the dependency is external. That is an implementation detail.

This now allows the subject class to be explicit about what it needs to perform its function, and by depending on an abstraction allows for substitutes to be used. For instance, when testing in isolation.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyClassTest {
  
    public void PublishTestSucceed() {
        // Arrange
        var dependency = new Mock<IExternalClass>();
        dependency
            .Setup(_ => _.publish(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(true);

        MyClass myC = new MyClass(dependency.Object);

        //Act
        bool result = myC.publish("asdf");

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }
}
```

If using `IExternalClass` explicitly as the dependency has too many restrictions then consider creating your own abstraction with an implementation that encapsulates/wraps the functionality of the external dependency.

That way you have more control over your code and are not restricted by the limitations of dependencies you have no control of.